# Flutter : Failed to build iOS app "ARCHIVE FAILED",Encountered error while archiving for device

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I was trying to generate the ipa file to upload it on App Store but unfortunately it failed and says "Encountered error while archiving for device".
I also tried Archiving from Xcode but, the Archive failed there too. It is working great in ios simulator (13)

Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** ARCHIVE FAILED **

Xcode's output:
Writing result bundle at path:

```
    /var/folders/8s/2st2j0d97k7cm80h3968jnx80000gn/T/flutter_tools.ph1v
            kd/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirZbRdRw/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    
        error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no
        further output
        CompileC
        
Failed to package /Users/sunsoft/Downloads/alifpet-app-master.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/sunsoft/Downloads/alifpet-app-master/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
    9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'Sodium' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sunsoft/Downloads/alifpet-app-master/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
    9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sunsoft/Downloads/alifpet-app-master/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
    9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'Starscream' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sunsoft/Downloads/alifpet-app-master/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 6.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
    9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sunsoft/Downloads/alifpet-app-master/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
    9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sunsoft/Downloads/alifpet-app-master/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
    9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'PusherSwiftWithEncryption' from project
    'Pods')
    /Users/sunsoft/Downloads/alifpet-app-master/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
    9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/sunsoft/Downloads/alifpet-app-master/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is
    set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is
    9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'AgoraRtcEngine_iOS' from project 'Pods')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/8s/2st2j0d97k7cm80h3968jnx80000gn/T/flutter_tools.ph1v
        kd/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirZbRdRw/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    
    Encountered error while archiving for device.
```

Comment: have you tried setting the IOS Deployment Target in xcode to 9?

Comment: I have set it 12, coz Xcode is recommending to target those above packages to be 12 so I have changed it to 12. please help with this. am going mad behind this, from past 2 days

Comment: 'flutter upgrade' fixed mine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that the Podfile that Flutter template creates by default has no specific iOS version set unfortunately.

Do this to fix this problem:

1. in `ios/` folder of your project, open the `Podfile`.
2. At top of `Podfile`, make sure this line is **not** commented out and change the iOS version to 12.0.

change from:

```
#platform :ios, '8.0'
```

to:

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
```

3. Run `pod deintegrate` in Terminal inside the `ios/` folder of your project.
4. Run `pod install --repo-update` in your `ios/` folder

This should do the trick!

If after this you are getting the following error

> CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target

Then you need to open your iOS workspace in Xcode and select your root project on top left, then inside the Info tab, choose your configuration (in this case Debug) and change it to None. After that, do pod install again.

[image]

Comment: [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`). Its showing this when I tried above solution

Comment: I updated my answer with more information on how you can fix this last issue you are facing.

Comment: The above issue which i have mentioned has been solved, pls plz plz help with last one issue, It will be great help to me that is: " [!] PusherSwiftEncryption has been deprecated in favour of pusher swift, I still dont know what is the reasen it is still failing to generate

Comment: So did you manage to fix this and if yes, did my solution help you fix it?

Comment: Almost helped except one, I would really appreciate u for responding to me, but it is still failing I guess the issue could be that deprecation above which i have mentioned, plz plz help me this last time it would be great help, am accepting this answer as a solved solution. just help me with this last issue

Comment: Are you using any APIs related to Pusher? Any of your dependencies perhaps in the pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: solved thanks a lot, for taking time to respond my issues, great help thanks

Comment: You're most welcome, my pleasure. How did you fix the last part?

Comment: I changed the dependency, I mean I replaced the dependency with another one. which solved my issue, Thank you soo much

Comment: Fantastic, well done for doing experimentation as well yourself. Great job.

Comment: Heyy I can't get past the last error ("CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of ..."). It's strange, I change my configuraiton in Xcode as per the screenshot, run `pod install` again and when I come back to Xcode the configuration is back to what it was. Feels like `pod install` is changing that file as part of the install process. @TheMoth can you expand on "replaced the dependency with another one"?

Answer (score 0):

My situation is a bit different, I even cannot build it, the error message was "PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" while I built it using Xcode so I follow @Taimoor Sikander solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/75976213/1603455

Then `flutter build ipa` on VSCode terminal that went successfully. Hope that helps.