# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code after updating to Xcode 14.3 and MacOS 13.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Had to update to Xcode 14, for which I also had to update to the MacOS 13, Ventura. Latest Apple recs. No problem, got those done. But now I can't Archive my project to upload to the App Store. Keep getting the error below.

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlWNF.jpg)

I noticed that lots of people on the Internet had this error while updating Xcode versions, and I tried these following solutions, but none of them worked for me.

- Delete DerivedData, CocaoPods Cache, pod deintegrate then pod install, clean build, rebuild
- Unlock and relock Keychain Access (mine is grayed out, so couldn't try this)
- Delete xcuserdata

It appears that my specific issue is being caused by Alamofire.framework not being found, and I'm not sure how to fix that. Tried changing the target version of AlamoFire to no avail. The error notes -

> /Projects/app/app/../../../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Alamofire.framework" failed: No such file or directory (2)

Any help in getting me unblocked here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you update Cocoapods to the latest version before doing the `pod` commands you mentioned?

Comment: can you check it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75975043/xcode-error-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code/75975271#75975271

Comment: if not please downgrade the Alamofire version (in podfile)

Comment: HangarRash - yes, I updated the pods.
Mazier - The first thing you suggested worked. Thank you!

Comment: @lizardcoder I asked if you updated Cocoapods, not if you updated your pods.

Comment: HangarRash - oh, I misread you. I hadn't updated CocoaPods, and just did.

Comment: HangarRash - you're right, the update also fixes the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should work.
Search `$(readlink`
You will find it in two places.
Insert a `-f` like this `"$(readlink -f "${source}")"` in both places.